# Python imported functions are not being executed - missing libraries

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-importlib

I am finalizing a project where I need to split the `requirements.txt` , `helper_functions.py` and , `libraries.py` -libraries that are used within the functions- into (3) separate files for code beautification .

I created the 3 files, uploaded them on my cloud and made them accessible to my google Colab notebook:

1. I downloaded the `requirements.txt` and installed the packages every
   time I run the jupyter notebook using the command `!pip install -r requirements.txt`
2. I downloaded the `helper_functions` and imported them into my
   environment using the command `from helper_functions import *` where
   I can see them.
3. This is the problem now, I downloaded the libraries.py and tried to
   import them using using the command `from libraries import *` or
   `%run -i libraries.py` . The problem I have is when I try to call
   any of the functions that require one of the libraries e.g boto3
   library or the shortcut of np (though both of them exist in my
   libraries.py file), I get an error of

   ```
   name 'boto3' is not defined
   name 'np' is not defined
   ```

Here are the snapshots of my files that are loaded into my Colab environment

```
`requrinments.txt`

boto3

numpy

`libraries.py file`

import boto3

import numpy as np

`helper_functions.py file`

def load_data(input):

data = np.(…..)
```

what should I do ?

Comment: This is probably just a series of typos, but  you currently list `requirements.txt`, `requirnments.txt` and `requrinments.txt`.  
However, based on the contents shown - `helper_functions.py` won't be able to see an import that's only occurring in `libaries.py`, which is why it doesn't know what boto3 or np are

Comment: imports only exist in the namespace of the script that imported them.  helper_functions.py doesn't import anything.

Comment: My helper functions contains only functions,  no libraries. My libraries function does. What's so weired is I am able to use np alias now that is imported from libraries but np doesn't work if it is part of the helper function body. How can I fix it?

Comment: Right - which is why it can't access anything from the libraries.....  Perhaps you need to review Python import basics?  `helper_functions.py` has no idea that `libraries.py` even exists.

Comment: `helper_functions.py` needs to import whichever modules it needs access to.  It should probably just have `import boto3` and `import numpy as np` directly in `helper_functions.py`, or you could have `helper_functions.py` call `from libraries import *`, but that's just adding an extra layer of obfuscation, and `from module import * ` should almost always be avoided as it can cause confusion in your namespace.

Comment: You haven't really clarified WHERE you are importing them.  Assuming you have a main script somewhere that you haven't shown, which I'll call `main.py`, importing the libraries into `main.py` only makes them available to main.  They have to be imported into helper_functions in order for it to see them.

Comment: So, I added both libraries to my helper and it is working. Thanks! I have the following points that I am giving them a try: 1) if I have these two libraries imported in my helper, can I use them in other general functions I am writing? The question is just to avoid loading the same library twice.  2) would it work if I import libraries file from helper function through from libraries import *. But no point to do it if I have to import   them again (I am simply importing them to my colab space), simple import from Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

Python modules are imported into a given namespace. To use a module of a module you can access it by module.submodule. However this is terrible to do and you should just about always import them directly into your module since almost all of the time they will be identical.

```
import mymod
np = mymod.numpy
```

The above should be akin to the below for all non-hacky code.

```
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 0):

The libraries related to the helper functions must exist in the same file, since libraries.py will import the libraries to a name space that helper functions file doesn't access it